# How do I handle table relationships with the repository pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, repository-pattern, one-to-many

I'm implementing the repository pattern as part of an ASP.NET MVC site. Most examples I've seen of repositories are fairly simple. For example here's a typical abstract repository interface.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> All();
    TEntity FindBy(int id);
    TEntity FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression);
    IQueryable<TEntity> FilterBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression);
    bool Add(TEntity entity);
    bool Update(TEntity entity);
    bool Delete(TEntity entity):
}
```

It's clear to me how you would use a repository like this to add, update, delete, or get entities of a single type. But how do you handle creating and manipulating one-to-many or many-to-many relationships between different types?

Say you have an `Item` type where each item is assigned to a `Category`. How would you make this assignment through the repository? Should this be up to the `Update(Category c)` and/or `Update(Item i)` methods to figure out what relationships need to be made to or from the element being updated? Or should there be an explicit `AssignCategoryToItem(Item i, Category c)` method?

If it makes any difference I'm using Fluent NHibernate to implement my concrete repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does your app handle assigning a category to an item?

Does it:

1. Allows the user to view the item then assign it a category
2. Allows the user to view the category then add items to it

Let your app dictate which method you pick.

This brings up the idea of having a `Business Logic/Services` layer and dealing with [**aggregate roots**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root). In my applications, I always have a `services` layer where all the business logic is at. I found that doing this has made my application easier to understand and maintain/refactor. (Note: I also use generic repositories and put the complex repository look ups in separate functions in the proper service class)

In your `services` layer, you'll have a function called `AssignCategoryToItem` which would then take the category (the aggregate root) and you would then add the item to that `category` and save the changes - although I would prefer passing in the `IDs` of the category and pulling it from the database before updating.

Comment: Ok I think that makes sense. One thing I'm not sure about is what logic would go in the "services" classes vs what would go in my actual model classes?

Comment: Let your model classes just represent models/application objects. Don't put logic in them - keep them simple. Have your services classes take care of the heavy lifting - i.e. database calls, complex business logic/validation. Have your models be the objects you use to transfer info from your repository/db to the services layer and back.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have defined your aggregate roots you should create very specific repository interfaces (such as IProductRepository) for these, and have your service layer consume them.

Such as...

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IList<Product> GetProductsInCategory(Category c);
    Product GetProductBy(int id);
    IList<Category> GetActiveProductCategories();
}
```

Then in your concrete implementation of IProductRepository you would consume the generic repository and query your related entities and join them as required.