# Creating a Service Layer for my MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

From what I understand, MVC separates the class definitions (model) from the presentation (view) via the "glue" that is the controller.  The controller should have a single responsibility and therefore be testable.  ViewModels are used to bring together data from multiple entities and to "massage" the data from the controller for the view.

It seems like business logic doesn't really have a place... so I'm thinking another layer for services would be suitable.  I'm just not sure where to place this layer, or how to build the services - should it be a class called "services" that contains a bunch of functions?  I'm a bit new to MVC, so any reading material, samples, or general newcomer kind of tips would be awesome.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I usually use a Service Layer when developing ASP.NET MVC application.  It is similar to the [Service Layer Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) that Martin Fowler discusses in *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*.  It encapsulates your business logic and make the controllers pretty thin.  Basically the controllers use the service layer to get the domain models that are then transformed into view models.  I also use the [Unit of Work Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) to handle transactions and the [Repository Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to encapsulate the data access layer for easier unit testing and being able to easily swap out ORM's.  This figure shows the typical layers that I use in an MVC application.

[image: MVC Architecture]

The service layer is labeled as the "Application or Domain Layer" in this diagram because I find people get confused when you use the term "Service Layer".  They tend to think that this is a web service.  It is actually an assembly which can be used by your favorite web service technology, such as ASP.NET Web API or WCF, as well as a controller.

As for naming conventions I usually use something that describes the domain followed by service. For example, If I have a service layer that handles user membership then I would have a class called MembershipService that has all of the methods needed by controllers and and web services to query and manipulate the membership domain. Note you may have several domains in the same application so you can have multiple service layers.  My point being here that you do not have to have one monolithic service that takes care of the whole application.

Comment: Is there a good example out there that implements this methodology?

Comment: @Animesh you have just to compose with examples in the net, EF + Code First or POCO template for DAL, T4Scaffolding for generating Repository and UnitOfWork, Service is just coordination betwen DAL and POCO encapsulating business logic. Then ASP.NET MVC Controller OR WebApi that only call service layer and show results (ASP.NET MVC) or expose it to other client (ASP.NET WebApi)

Comment: The repository and UoW is unnecessary, isn't it? At least in your example, when you have to use just to one database technology (and it's not DDD). This is why EF already has implemented UoW and repository patterns itself.

Comment: I don't know about here, as I like the example and graphic, but lots of tutorials online use the Repository Pattern needlessly.  They abstract because they can abstract with no benefit, just so they can use an Interface.

Comment: Awesome !!! Thank you @kevin Junghans, Your answer really helped me architect complex web application. One short question, While developing micro services based web apps, Do we need to implement Service classes or simply MVC classes does the job.

Comment: Business logic should be in model.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive part: "[Services are] all of the methods needed by controllers and web services to query and manipulate the membership domain". Now, what's the exact meaning of domain?

Answer (score 29):

My advice is to create a separate classes called "services". Put them in different class library (or namespace) project and make them independent on MVC framework infrastructure. I recommend to use also some kind of dependency injection (the best is constructor injection). Then your service classes may look like:

```
 public class MyService : IMyService
 {
     IFirstDependency _firstService;
     ISecondDependency _secondService;

     public MyService(IFirstDependency firstService, ISecondDependency secondService)
     {
     }

     public Result DoStuf(InputDTO)
     {
         // some important logic         
     }
 }
```

Then you consume these service from your controllers. 
Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection_topic2) for complete example.

According Repositories - my advice is to do not use them if you are going to use some modern ORM (NHibernate, EntityFramework), because your business logic will be encapsulated in the Service Layer and your database will be already encapsulated with the ORM framework.

Comment: I think the problem with skipping the repository section and going right to the ORM is that your service classes will directly get the ORM context which means all those classes in your service will have access to all the tables you pulled into the context instead of each service class working with only the tables it needs. You could avoid this by passing in DbSet's into the ctor of each class and resolving that with DI but you may run into issues with that?

Answer (score 12):

Quoting from  [“Business logic should be in a service, not in a model”?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/218394/173682):

In an MVP/MVC/MVVM/MV* architecture, services don't exist at all. Or if they do, the term is used to refer to any generic object that can be injected into a controller or view model. The business logic is in your model. If you want to create "service objects" to orchestrate complicated operations, that's seen as an implementation detail. A lot of people, sadly, implement MVC like this, but it's considered an anti-pattern (Anemic Domain Model) because the model itself does nothing, it's just a bunch of properties for the UI.

Some people mistakenly think that taking a 100-line controller method and shoving it all into a service somehow makes for a better architecture. It really doesn't; all it does is add another, probably unnecessary layer of indirection. Practically speaking, the controller is still doing the work, it's just doing so through a poorly named "helper" object. I highly recommend Jimmy Bogard's [Wicked Domain Models](http://vimeo.com/43598193) presentation for a clear example of how to turn an anemic domain model into a useful one. It involves careful examination of the models you're exposing and which operations are actually valid in a business context.

Comment: This is the best answer. The selected one says to put business logic on services to be used in controller, but business logic should be on the model.

Comment: @MateusFelipe Ok, let's say I don't implement the business logic from the services, as suggested here, how do I implement that logic from within the models?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404093.aspx) from MSDN best practices.

Source code of the application in article can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27290).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you'd be after something like a repository pattern. You can read about it here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

This answer here may also help:

[Best Repository Pattern for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925257/best-repository-pattern-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: It's far more than just the repository pattern. Services are about data access _too_, but not exclusively imho.

Comment: As far as I've read, services and RP are different things.