# Creating a Service Layer for MVC4 Applications while honoring Single Responsibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to learn some best practices while I ramp up on MVC4.  I have a solution with three projects:

1. Web: MVC stuff
2. Core: Data Model
3. Tests: Testing classes

I'm now trying to add:

4: Services: Business Logic

This will take logic such as "GetFilteredItems()" from my controllers and place them into a Service project, which depends on Core, and upon which Web depends.  As I'm beginning to do this, I want to honor single responsibility and create one class per method.  My questions:

1) Is this a good approach?
2) Say I need a GetFilteredItems method that takes an ID and returns a List.  What's the convention here in terms of naming classes and methods?  I can't have a class SampleClass with a method SampleClass() that returns something, right?

Comment: these are great questions, but this is NOT the right forum for them. If you want good answers, I suggest you post this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a good discussion on [creating a service layer in MVC here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887871/creating-a-service-layer-for-my-mvc-application/14896644#14896644).

Single responsibility does not require classes with single methods.  I have never heard of this approach before. Where is there a discussion on this approach and its benefits?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this seems like a good approach, although the single responsibility principle doesn't necessarily mean that you need to create a separate class per method.

Just make sure that your service classes have a single responsibility.

For your GetFilteredItems method, you could create a class called ItemService to contain this.
This service would also contain any other methods for returning collections of items.

You could then put methods pertaining to persisting items in a different service, and so on...