# What is wrong in this c# code for simple RestApi?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, code-structure

I received feedback:

"code test is not at the expected level there's a lack of understanding of async, HTTP clients, and just software development patterns in general. Poor structure and testing"

The simple test and solution are on GitHub https://github.com/sasa-yovanovicc/weatherapi

I'll really appreciate any help to understand what is wrong because the code works, the test works,, and covers all solutions, and honestly, I don't know what they expect.

I understand that in OOP code can be more abstracted and complex, but I can't see any purpose in making code more complex than needed to solve a given problems.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person giving this feedback? BTW: the link is not working

Comment: @KlausGütter I asked but never received detailed feedback. I also aks for an example. Nothing.
Beause of this I ask community. If I doing something wrong, ok, I need know what.

Comment: @KlausGütter repo wasprivate, now is public

Answer (score 1):

There are few improvements which can be made, that will not only follow modern practices, but simplify the code in some cases:

1. Use `IHttpClientFactory` (previously instantiating `HttpClient` per request was considered a bad practice - see [here](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [here](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) why, though now situation was improved, also see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)). For possible usage patterns check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
2. Use strongly-typed configs for example with [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
3. There is literally no reason to use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in your code, for example in `WeatherController`:

   ```
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
        var weatherResponse = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<WeatherResponse>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In my view, code can be improved in this area:

1. This piece of code should be placed in [Service layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887871/creating-a-service-layer-for-my-mvc-application). This code is placed in `AstronomyController`

   ```
   HttpClient httpClient = new();
   var responseAstro = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestURIAstro);
   ```

   Usually, controllers should not have any logic. It should coordinate and orchestrate services.
2. If this `Helper` class has the `StringHelper` name, it will be more readable:

   ```
    public class StringHelper
   ```

   So it can be concluded that if `StringHelper` would have code snippet that will contain code which helps to work with `int` type,
   then it would be violation of [Single Responsibility Principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345018/when-using-the-single-responsibility-principle-what-constitutes-a-responsibili) of [SOLID principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692126/cant-seem-to-understand-solid-principles-and-design-patterns).
3. Using `GetResult()` can be [a potential reason of a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007006/is-getawaiter-getresult-safe-for-general-use)

   ```
   var r = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ErrorResponse>()
       .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   ```

   So it is better to use `await`:

   ```
   var r = await response.Content
       .ReadFromJsonAsync<ErrorResponse>();
   // the other code is omitted for the brevity
   ```
4. It is better to write tests by [triple A pattern](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/title-testing-code-ocd-and-the-aaa-pattern-df453975ab80). In addition, try to use abstractions when you will write code for controllers. [Read more about how to test controllers here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

   E.g.:

   ```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBrainstormSessionRepository _sessionRepository;
        // the other code is omitted for the brevity
   ```

   Here `IBrainstormSessionRepository` is an abstraction. Moreover, read this article "[Unit testing best practices with .NET Core and .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices)" is very helpful.
5. Multiple `Assert` should be avoided in tests. There is a very nice book by Roy Osherove’s "The Art of Unit Testing". [One of the things that Osherove warns against is multiple asserts in unit tests.](http://www.owenpellegrin.com/blog/testing/how-do-you-solve-multiple-asserts/)  That is, one should generally avoid writing tests that can fail for more than one reason.

   E.g., here should be just one `Assert`:

   ```
   Assert.NotNull(result);
   Assert.IsType<ObjectResult>(result);

   var objectResult = result as ObjectResult;
   Assert.NotNull(objectResult);

   var model = objectResult.Value as InfoMessage;
   Assert.NotNull(model);
   ```