# What type to return when querying multiple entities in Repository layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have the following layers involved in this question:

- Service Layer (Using IoC to call Repository)
- Domain Model (POCO / Domain Entities, defined repository Interfaces)
- Repository Layer (EF .edmx and implemented repositories)

A lot of times it's really straight forward: Repository layer queries database via Entity Framework and returns `IList<SomeDomainEntity>` to caller which was Service Layer. The *type* returned is a type defined in the Domain Model.

The problem I'm running into is when I need to query across POCOs A,B, and C and get data from all to be returned. Since I don't handle any logic in the repository I need to return this data back to the Service layer to be processed (either directly or more likely by calling some logic on domain model). However I don't have a *single type* anymore from the results of the repository query to return to the caller.

An anonymous type of course handles this in examples I see, but since I'm not processing that logic from returned data directly in the Repository and it needs to be returned, I need a physical type to return. Here are some solutions I thought of but not sure I like any:

1. Create a new domain entity in Domain Model that essentially is a composition of all the data I queried, so this new single type may be returned. This seems wrong to create abritrary types to satisy query needs.
2. Make the service layer call the individual repositories on A,B,C entities separately and then deal with the data from each returned object. This seems like a lot of extra work.
3. Create a ViewModel to return. This seems out of place to me as well. I leverage ViewModel classes heavily between my service layer and UI layers, but never seen them leveraged for return from the repository.

I can't be the only one querying across multiple entities to get a conglomeration of data back that needs to be added to a type and returned to the caller. What is a common practice or standard way of going about this to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I would go with option 1. Create views based on your queries and map the views to your new domain models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If those entities are **related** and you query all of them in one place then you should try to find an [aggregate root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root) of them in your domain model or if it doesn't exist yet you should introduce a new one, as you said in the first option. This is not wrong until it makes sense. It should model a domain concept and you probably have one because you created that repository method.

If those entities are **not related** (well, probably related in some way, but not that tightly as above) and you just want to get them in one go then you should handle that in the service layer where you can use multiple repositories and compose a result object.

You probably heard of the concept of [navigation properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738520%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) but I write it here because it may be another answer to your question (I don't see your domain model)

I wouldn't go with your third suggestion (create viewmodels in the repository) because it breaks the separations.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that clears things up a lot. Really small detail question - do you separate aggregate root entities into their own folder say 'AggregateRootEntities' for distinction?

Comment: No, the distinction is not that sharp, they are first class citizens most of the time :) but this isn't too important so organize it in a way you feel yourself comfortable.

Comment: So allowing them to reside in a 'DomainEntities' or 'Entities' folder would be acceptable as well? Meaning, I don't have to so clearly define them as aggregate root entities.

Comment: Yes. They are 'aggregate root entities' because you use them in that way.

Answer (score 3):

Different entities can relate to each other whithout one of them being an aggregate root. Services are used to these kind of queries. I usually do something like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    IEnumerable<UserWithMessages> Find()
    {
        var messages = _messageRepository.FindAll();
        var userIds = _messages.Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().ToArry();
        var users = _userRepository.Find(userIds);
        return users.Select(x => new UserWithMessages(x, messages.Where(x => x.UserId == x.Id));
    }
}
```

It's just two DB queries which can utilize indexes in the DB. So It should be pretty fast.

Comment: To map this sample to my example, I would already have classes named `messages` and `users`. However `UserWithMessages` is something I would have to create and acts like an aggregate root composing certain elements of the 2 individual classes, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use DTO (Data Transfer Objects) for this purpose. It's a common practice to separate your service layer from the view, and DTOs allow you to share only the important information necessary for the views.

There are various ways to implement this part of the system depending of the size of the system. In small systems you can use extension methods to map your POCO entities in data transfer objects

I suggest you take a look to "AutoMapper". I think this will be really usefull for you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/

Comment: I actually do use DTOs and ViewModels in the *upper* layers of my architecture, but my question really focused on the *lower* layers including the repository and domain model.

Comment: I think your repository layer only need to know about domain entities. It's work of another layer (application layer in DDD) to map and prepare this data for the view