# Should I define a repository for each entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I have been learning about MVC and I am using Entity Framework. What I am trying to understand is repositories. Every tutorial I've read deals with one entity and at that level I have a understanding, but what about multiple tables. I use a variation of code-first, where I associate my model classes with an existing database. In my database,there are three tables; User, Journey and UserJourney (linked table). User and Journey have a many-to-many relationship. Should I have a repository for each entity? Has aggregates any use here? In the long run I want to query the database to find user's journeys and pass to a view.

My question is perhaps vague, but I am quite confused on this matter, so any help in understanding this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Normally repositories should not be defined for each entity but rather per [`aggregate root`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root). You have entities that cannot live by themselves, but are related to some parent entity. This parent entity is called aggregate root and you should have a repository for each of them.

Comment: Ok, I have User and Journey tables that have a many to many relationship. So I now also have a linked UserJourney table. Would these three tables make up an aggregate? What would be the aggregate root? I assume User.

Answer (score 2):

Search for a concept called GenericRepository. It will help in getting rid of the repository for each entity problem. Sample below:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(T entity);
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    readonly MyDbContext _context;
    readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;
    public GenericRepository(PfsDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entityToUpdate)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        _context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (_context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        var entityToDelete = _dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }
  }
```

You can then use it as

```
var userRepository = new GenericRepository<User>(_context);
var journeyRepository = new GenericRepository<Journey>(_context);
```