# How to integrate a Linq to Entity query that queries multiple entities in a repository and send data to View?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, repository-pattern

I'm learning MVC, the repository pattern and EF and I need some advice as to how best to integrate a method which contains a query that queries multiple entities into the repository.

At the moment, I have created a repository class which implements an interface and uses an instance of DbContext to retrieve data from the database using the Entity Framework, but for one entity.

Edited...
I have the GetJourneys() method in my repository, however I am unsure how to obtain the Journey details from the query in the Controller. I can get the User details.

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetJourneys()
    {
        var todayDate = DateTime.Now;

        //Woking with many to many Relationship 
        //(join tables) in Asp.net MVC/Entity Framework
        var viewModel = from j in dbContext.Users
                        from u in dbContext.Journeys
                        where u.DepartDate >= todayDate.Date
                        orderby u.DepartDate ascending
                        select j;

        return viewModel.ToList();
    }
```

Below is my User entity

```
public class User
{
    [Key, Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30), Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30), Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProfileImg { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30), Required]
    public string FbLink { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Journey> Journeys { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my Controller

```
public ViewResult Search()
    {
        var userJourneyList = from user in repository.GetJourneys() select user;
        var searchView = new List<SearchViewModel>();
        try
        {
            if (userJourneyList.Any())
            {
                foreach (var user in userJourneyList)
                {
                    searchView.Add(new SearchViewModel()
                    {
                        //JourneyDestination = user.Journeys.FromDestination,
                        //JourneyDate = user.Journeys.DepartDate,
                        UserName = user.FirstName,
                        ProfileImage = user.ProfileImg,
                        //SeatsAvailable = user.Journeys.SeatsAvailable,
                        //UserType = user.Journeys.UserType
                    });
                }
                returnAmount = 1;
                ViewBag.Amount = returnAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                returnAmount = 0;
                ViewBag.Amount = returnAmount;
            }
            var todayDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return View(searchView.ToList());
    }
```

**UPDATE** In my repository now

```
public IList<User> GetAllUsersWithJourneys()
    {
        using (var db = new EfDbContext())
        {
            var users = from userJourney in db.Users.Include(i => i.Journeys)
                        select userJourney;
            return users.ToList();
        }
    }
```

However, I still don't understand how to get the journey details. My User and Journey entities are correct in terms of a many-to-many relationship. Below is the controller with the new repository method.

```
        var userJourney = repository.GetAllUsersWithJourneys();
        var searchView = new List<SearchViewModel>();
        try
        {
            if (userJourneyList.Any())
            {
                foreach (var user in userJourney)
                {
                    searchView.Add(new SearchViewModel()
                        {
                            UserName = user.FirstName,
                            JourneyDestination = user.Journeys.ToDestination //ERROR
                        });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //user will be notified that no results were found and that they are given the option to create the journey that they seek
                returnAmount = 0;
                ViewBag.Amount = returnAmount;
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return View(searchView.ToList());
```

My ViewModel looks like this

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; } //User
    public string JourneyDestination { get; set; } //Journey
    public DateTime JourneyDate { get; set; } //Journey
    public string UserName { get; set; } //User
    public int SeatsAvailable { get; set; } //Journey
    public bool UserType { get; set; } //Journey
}
```

Comment: What's the conceptual relationship between `User` and `Journey`?

Comment: Many to many is the relationship

Comment: In your second "controller" code block, on the line commented "ERROR", it looks like you're assigning a value typed as `ICollection<Journey>` to a property typed as `string`. Is that what your code really is?

Comment: @SteveRuble I updated the line your were describing.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're trying to do is flatten all user journeys into a single list (assumption based on the shape of the model you're passing to the view), then one way to do it would be like this:

```
var userJourney = repository.GetAllUsersWithJourneys();
var searchView = new List<SearchViewModel>();
try
{   
    if (userJourneyList.Any())
    {
        foreach (var user in userJourney)
        {
            foreach(var journey in user.Journeys)
            {
                searchView.Add(new SearchViewModel()
                    {
                        UserName = user.FirstName,
                        JourneyDestination = journey.JourneyDestination
                    });                
            }
        }
    }
}
 catch (NullReferenceException ex)
 {
     // ... 
 }
```

Alternatively, you could refactor it to be more functional:

```
var userJourney = repository.GetAllUsersWithJourneys();
var searchView = userJourney.SelectMany(
    user => user.Journeys.Select(
        journey => new SearchViewModel()
            {
                UserName = user.FirstName,
                JourneyDestination = journey.JourneyDestination
            }
        )
    )
    .ToList();        

if (!searchView.Any())
{
    // no results logic
}
```

The second method would be even better if your repository returned `IQueryable<User>` instead of calling `ToList()` and returning `IList<User>`, **BUT** that won't work with your repository disposing the `DbContext` right away. As it stands (using `ToList()`), you're going to end up doing more processing in memory than you would if you let SQL do the work. If your repository knew about `SearchViewModel`, you could do this:

```
public IList<SearchViewModel> GetSearchViewModels()
{
    using (var db = new EfDbContext())
    {
        var users = from user in db.Users
                    from journey in user.Journeys
                    select new SearchViewModel()
                    {
                        UserName = user.FirstName,
                        JourneyDestination = journey.JourneyDestination
                     }
                    select userJourney;

        return users.ToList();
    }
}
```

However, that may be an unacceptable mixing of presentation and data layers, depending on how strict your architecture is.

Comment: Thanks for the help Steve, but with no success. My goal is to read all journeys and their user and show in a list in the view. User and Journey have a many-to-many relationship. Is it correct to use Eager Loading to get the data?

Comment: @ColinRoe, what went wrong? Yes, you should use eager loading in this case.

Comment: I call the method GetAllUsersWithJourneys in the controller but I don't get any Journey data from the query. When I try to assign values to the properties in the SearchViewModel within the foreach loop, I cannot access the Journey properties (e.g. JourneyDestination = journey.ToDestination) not that they contain anything at the moment. Is there an issue with my eager loading within the GetAllUsersWithJourneys method and how I access the data in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

> how best to integrate a method which contains a query that queries multiple entities into the repository.

Considering the relationship between `User` and `Journey`, you should decide which entity owns the relationship and use `Aggregate Root` to fetch data.

The description of `Aggregate Root` at [What's an Aggregate Root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root) would be helpful.

**Update:**

Entities

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Journeys = new List<Journey>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Journey> Journeys { get; set; }
}

public class Journey
{
    public Journey()
    {
        this.Users = new List<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Repositiories

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public IList<User> GetAllUsersWithJourneys()
    {
         //Fetch all Users; Include Journeys 
    }
}

public class JourneyRepository
{
    public IList<Journey> GetAllJourneysWithUsers()
    {
         //Fetch all journeys; Include Users 
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class UserJourneyViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int JourneyId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller's Action

```
public ViewResult Search()
{
    // Use UserRepository or JourneyRepository to make a list of
    // UserJourneyViewModel that provides appropriate data for the view.  
}
```

Comment: I have included my User entity above. User would be the Root. I tried changing the relationship to an one to one relationship just to see if I could obtain the Journey data from the query in the controller and I was successful. With the relationship being many to many is there something wrong with my User entity and how can I obtain the data from the query relating to the Journey details.

Comment: I think the `Search` method is not actually a search, it fetches all users with their journeys. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it is just the name of the Action

Comment: OK, I will update the answer with my solution for Many-to-Many relationship. I hope, it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However, I'm still unable to get the Journey data when I fetch all Users, including Journeys. I edited my original question based on your feedback

Comment: Have you initialized the `Journeys` collection in the constructor of `User`?