# DDD Pattern for long running background processing

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I hope this makes sense.

I notice some of my applications need to run indefinately to perform some type of process.  or periodically run a process depending on time that has passed.  Is there any advice/patterns on this located in any of the popular DDD books?

Thanks

Comment: You may be instrested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414951/how-to-use-rich-domain-with-massive-operations/19416703#19416703)

Comment: By "run indefinitely", do you mean that it needs to do a lot of work (e.g. process thousands of database records) or do you mean that the process needs to wait for some real-life event, such a shipment that physically arrives at the destination?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with DDD. I think you're describing a service that may draw upon DDD principles.