# Aggregates in CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, aggregateroot

What are aggregates and how are they used in CQRS (Command-Query-Responsibility-Segregation) and ES (Event-Sourcing)? I'm new to this kind of architecture, and I'd be really happy if someone could please explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: One little search for CQRS and Event Sourcing will anwser your question

Comment: Duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root

Answer (score 14):

First I'd like to quote [Martin Fowler's blog post on CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and note that **Aggregates are rather related to Domain Driven Design then to CQRS**.

> CQRS naturally fits with some other architectural patterns.
>
> - As we move away from a single representation that we interact with via CRUD, 
>     we can easily move to a task-based UI.
> - Interacting with the command-model naturally falls into commands or events, 
>     which meshes well with [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).
> - Having separate models raises questions about how hard to keep those models
>     consistent, which raises the likelihood of using [eventual consistency](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2008/12/eventually_consistent.html).
> - For many domains, much of the logic is needed when you're updating, 
>     so it may make sense to use [EagerReadDerivation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EagerReadDerivation.html) to simplify 
>     your query-side models.
> - CQRS is suited to complex domains, the kind that also benefit from 
>     [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

In terms of Domain-Driven Design Aggregate is a logical group of Entities and Value Objects that are treated as a single unit ([OOP, Composition](http://guruzon.com/1/oop-concepts/inheritance-and-composition/aggregation-vs-composition-vs-association-difference-comparison-between)). Aggregate Root is a single one Entity that all others are bound to.