# Managing Relationships for an Entity

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm having a few issues with figuring out what is responsible for managing relationships within entities.

Say I have an entity:

```
public class Customer : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

And a repository called CustomerRepository. The customer repository can get a collection of customers from a persistent data source, and add and remove from said data source.

So far so good, I'm following the single responsibility principle. However, when I try to dot into the Assets for a customer:

```
CustomerRepository repo = new CustomerRepository();
var customer = repo.FindById(1);
var assets = customer.Assets;
```

I'll find that the assets aren't populated. The answer to this is to populate the assets somewhere... But where?!

I could do a more complicated get method in the Customer entity Assets property, with another repository for assets (AssetRepository), but this would violate the single responsibility principle. Not only is the Customer entity responsible for structuring data, but also for relationships.

I could populate the Assets directly in the repository, at the same time a customer entity is created, but again, this surely gives the repository more responsibility than it should have. It's now creating and populating two sets of entities and assigning the Assets collection for the for a Customer, which gets even more inefficient and unwieldy when managing a collection of Customers (say in a Find() or GetActiveCustomers() methods). Not to mention if assets has another collection of entities within it, then the repository will be populating lots of different types of entity within entities within entities etc.

I feel as though I've missed something fundamental in the design, but no amount of googling is giving me the answer.

So in summary, what should be responsible for managing the relationships between entities, and populating the data for said entities.

I should also mention that I'm not using entity framework for this, so any pre-built implementation part of EF wouldn't be suitable, but adapting a pattern that EF generates would be acceptable.

Comment: Sounds like you want to read up on aggregate roots, try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root

Comment: At some point the repository has to represent a real life situation. The repository has customers - do these customers not have assets and are these not created at the same time?

Comment: The customers do have assets, and they should be created at the same time. So I guess that would make the repository responsible for creating and associating the assets to a customer at customer creation time. However, the assets will also have labels, which will need to be created and associated at the same time, the labels also have items, so I'm worried that it might get quite unmanageable using this composition. Labels also need to be managed on their own, without a binding to an asset, so that would be another repository I guess. I think @Mant101 is right, I'm researching Aggregates now

Comment: Also remember Einstein - "things should be as simple as possible, but no simpler"