# Should I save related models in repository?

Tags: laravel, domain-driven-design

I am working with Laravel for almost two years and trying to understand all the benefits of using Repositories and DDD. I still struggle with how to use best practices for working with data and models for better code reusability and nicer Architecture.

I have seen other developers suggesting to generate models in factories and then use Repositories for saving these models like :

```
public function add(User $user)
{
    return $user->save();
}
```

but what should I do, in case my user model has models related with it, like images, description and settings.

Should I create repository for each model and call ->add() function 4 times in the controller or should I place the saving logic inside the UserRepository ->add() function passing all models as well as user? Also, how about update function, that logic might also be quite complicated.

---

Update - what I need is a practical example with realization.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to understand DDD? Have you checked the concept of *aggregate*? Repository is a tactical pattern, a small part of DDD, which is not the most important.

Comment: You should read about Aggregate Root. Take a look ate this explanation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I have read the definition, and I totally agree with the structuring ideas, because they are obvious. The thing that I have not found is how to implement that in Laravel. Searching Laravel Aggregate root does not give me any practical examples for saving/updating related models.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I was not saying that I think that Laravel is designed with DDD in mind, I was just asking if anybody has an idea of the correct structure and approach if using Laravel framework. If you search Laravel + DDD in google - there are a lot of devs suggesting on how to implement DDD with Laravel, but no info on more or less complicate questions on exact implementation (and sometimes even simple ones).

Comment: I combined my two last comments to an answer, I am not sure if it is good enough or not. The issue with DDD, not the issue really but rather a challenge, is that it is more like a mindset of the domain analysis and a combination of strategic and tactical patterns. What we often see is that people concentrate on tactical patterns and ignore the strategic part, which is hardly discouraged by any DDD practitioner. Really, check the blue book or at least a Pluralsight course to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always difficult to deal with "right way" questions.  But here is one way.

From a DDD perspective, in this specific context, treat the User object as an aggregate root entity and the other objects as child value objects.

```
$description = new UserDescripton('Some description');
$image1 = new UserImage('head_shot','headshot.jpg');
$image2 = new UserImage('full_body','fullbody.jpg');

$user = new User('The Name',$description,[$image1,$image2]);

$userRepository->persist($user);
```

First thing to note is that you if really want to try and apply some of the ddd concepts then it is important to think in terms of domain models without worrying about how to persist them.  If you find that you are basically writing a CRUD app with a bunch of getters and setters and almost no business logic then pretty much forget about it.  All you will end up doing is to add complexity without much value.

The persist line is where the user will get stored.  And you certainly don't want to have to write a bunch of code to store and update the children.  Likewise, it would normally be waste of effort to make repositories for value objects.  If you are going this route then you really need some sort of database layer that understands individual objects as well as their relations.  It is the relations that are the key.

I assume you are using Laravel's Eloquent active record persistence layer.  I'm not familiar enough with it to know how easy it is to persist and update an aggregate root.

The code I showed is actually based more on Doctrine 2 Object Relation Mapper and pretty much works out of the box.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/  It is easy enough to integrate it with Laravel.

But even Doctrine 2 is largely CRUD oriented.  In different domain contexts, the user object will be treated differently.  It can start to get a bit involved to basically have different user implementations for different contexts.  So make sure that the payoff in the domain layer is worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It might not be the exact answer I was looking for, but it gave me an idea, of the way I should think and what to seek. I have also found some nice articles inside on how to work with Account and Entries which is a very nice example. Always wanted to understand that field. Eloquent by the way also has some ways to save relative models, though it is not as elegant. It looks like $user->save() and after $user->images()->save($image), $user->description()->save($description). And these methods will only save if models are new, or they have been updated.

Comment: may I also ask one question. Where am I supposed to put different statistics methods, like counting the number of users or sum of views of user profiles. I understand that it is supposed to be in a class in the User domain - but should that class be the UserRepository or another one like UserStatistics class?

Comment: Both of those stats are essentially database queries.  I would put them in the repo.  If the repo starts to become unmanageable then I would break it up.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have almost made my mind with how to approach the DDD

Answer (score 1):

I am not a PHP guy but from what I can find, Laravel an MVC framework, which has nothing to do with DDD.

Check [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/wajrcs/domain-driven-design-40360927), it does not to go to domain modelling, more concentrating on tactics but at least it has some goodness like command handling and domain events, briefly explains repositories with active record.

It also has references to two iconic DDD books at the last slide, I suggest you have a look at those too.

Comment: Man, I have upvoted your answer, because it puts some light on some of the concepts of DDD that I was interested in, but unfortunately they don't answer the question - what is the right approach to save and update related models in repository.