# Java: Spring Boot class constructor with too many DI's?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, constructor

Let's say I have a Spring Boot class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private MessagingService messagingService;
    private ClientReportFactoryImpl clientReportFactory;
    private TerminalReportFactoryImpl terminalReportFactory;
    private XMLView xmlView;
    private PrepareXMLService prepareXMLService;
```

And I have a constructor in that class:

```
@Autowired
    public SomeClass (ApplicationContext applicationContext, MessagingService messagingService, ClientReportFactoryImpl clientReportFactory,
                                                                TerminalReportFactoryImpl terminalReportFactory,
                                                                XMLView xmlView,
                                                                PrepareXMLService prepareXMLService) {
        Assert.notNull(applicationContext, "ApplicationContext must not be null!");
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        Assert.notNull(messagingService, "MessagingService must no be null!");
        this.messagingService = messagingService;
        Assert.notNull(clientReportFactory, "ClientReportFactory must not be null!");
        this.clientReportFactory = clientReportFactory;
        Assert.notNull(terminalReportFactory, "TerminalReportFactory must not be null!");
        this.terminalReportFactory = terminalReportFactory;
        Assert.notNull(xmlView, "XMLView must not be null!");
        this.xmlView = xmlView;
        Assert.notNull("PrepareXMLService must not be null");
        this.prepareXMLService = prepareXMLService;
    }
```

Is it considered bad practice to use that many dependencies in a class constructor? Should I refactor my classes so that there are only 1-2 DI's in a constructor?

Comment: It really depends on your overall application structure. But it is generally considered a bad practice to have too many dependencies. It is a good idea to often think about why are all these services required in a single class. Single Responsibility Principle - Not necessary to follow it strictly, but good to think about often

Comment: This is the reason I want to make changes. I think it is a bad design to have so many DI's in a single class. I need to refactor and see if I can remove some of the responsibilities of this class and delegate them somewhere else.

Comment: Why do you even need all those dependencies in your `Application` class. That should, generally, be only for configuration/bootstrap and shouldn't contain logic. Looks like you are injecting them to be used in other `@Bean` methods.

Comment: That is correct, but I think the latest version of Spring doesn't require that any more. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't invoke all of your services right in `Application` class, there is a nice guide on [how to structure your code](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) (this and the following chapters) so it could look like this:

```
com
+- example
 +- myproject
     +- Application.java
     |
     +- domain
     |   +- Customer.java
     |   +- CustomerRepository.java
     |
     +- service
     |   +- CustomerService.java
     |
     +- web
         +- CustomerController.java
```

Basically the idea is, that your `Services` are being [annotated with attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) like `@Service` (obviously), so that they would be picked up by `@ComponentScan` in your `Application`.

Comment: I am asking about the amount of DI in general per class. Application class was a bad example here. My bad.

Comment: I see. So the only thing I could tell - from my personal experience there are not more that 3 injections per class,  otherwise I would start thinking about how to externalize these dependencies.

Comment: I heard about the requirement of 5. But then again, what about the situation when I have to run a Service which could use multiple tables to collect data. Then in theory I could use quite a lot of repositories due to the complexity of the queues.

Comment: If you can influence the design of the repositories also, you might consider thinking of aggregate roots here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root), where you might end up with a fewer amount of repositories. At least I figured out, that most of the time I didn't need a repository for each single entity... But don't know if this might help in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: maybe you've to consider the microservice architecture and distribute the concerne per micro-service. also you've to be aware of too many injections as it could be/become a SPOF. Testability will be hard as you'll have to mock as many services as you inject what will make even the test code unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

depending on your application if you need dependancies defined there is a cleaner way to reduce constructor code by using Lombok annotation:  `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Inject})`

This will auto Inject all the dependancies defined as
`private final Dependency1 dep1;`