# Identifying Aggregates when some entity is shared?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, domain-model

Let’s say we have a simple data structure:[image]

Both, `Interface` and `Network Printer` have `EndPoint`, which is stored in the different table (with FKs enforced). For example, `Interface` requires `EndPoint’s` port numbers be between: 1000-2000 and `Network Printer` requires port numbers between: 2000-3000. It makes me think that `EndPoint` can’t be an aggregate root as we don't really need direct access to it and we don’t want directly change endpoint values without knowing its context. Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958722/2827454): if something belongs to one aggregate, then other aggregates might refer it as a read-only data. Does mean that `EndPoint` can’t belong to `Interface` *and* `Network Printer`? Or it still can, as in my case, the same `EndPoint` instance *is never shared* between the two aggregates. So `Interface` and `Network Pritner` always will be updating its own `EndPoint` and no consistency violation will happen? Sounds right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't explained your domain, but to me an `EndPoint` doesn't sound like an entity at all and would rather be a value (immutable). Changing the end point would simply consist of replacing the entire old `EndPoint` value with a new one. Immutable values may be shared across aggregate instances without issues because well, they can't change.

Still, if somehow `EndPoint` must be an entity then as long as **instances** are not shared across aggregates it is fine. There is no restrictions on using the same **kind** of entity in multiple aggregates.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like something still can be represented as ValueObject even it is actually stored in the table with ID field. ID just not exposed on domain level?

Comment: @Tenek Can't you simply have the data in the same table? I mean, you can have a dedicated endpoint table even if it's a value, but then from the persistence model perspective it will be an entity and from the model perspective it will be a value (most likely with a hidden ID).

Comment: Data comes from legacy DB. Right now EndPoint table is referenced from 3 different places, but values are never shared. I will do hidden Id field for domain object or even avoid it at all, as EndPoint can be looked up by repository from its context anyway. Having EndPoint as value object helped me to avoid exposing its repository and simplified whole structure. Thanks for advising!