# I have two different aggregates in the same bounded context and they both need to be created - should I use eventual consistency vs. Domain Service?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-service

Say I have an Aggregate call JobSeeker and another one that is called ResumeBank that contains a collection of resumes and is associated with a JobSeeker.

The business problem: When I create a JobSeeker I also need to create a ResumeBank that is associated with that JobSeeker.

Should I create a Domain Service that orchestrates this or should I use eventual consistency?

Comment: Hi Mike. What are the benefits of creating a Domain Service vs using eventual consistency?

Comment: Even if you create a Domain Service, they still remain eventually consistent if they are two separate aggregates as you specified. Could you rephrase the question pls?

Comment: Yes my question is should I create a Domain Service to make two calls: First to create the JobSeeker aggregate and the second to create the ResumeBank with the JobSeeker ID? Or do I have the ResumeBank aggregate subscribe to a "JobSeekerCreated" event and create the ResumeBank from there?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can define your JobSeeker aggregate as a root aggregate and use a repository to manage the consistency.

A nice post explains those notions [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root)

Comment: The JobSeeker is the Aggregate Root for the JobSeeker aggregate and the ResumeBank is the Aggregate Root for a separate aggregate.