# Efficient Data Binding for Complex Structures in Blazor Components

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor

I'm relatively new to Blazor and I'm facing challenges with effectively binding complex data structures, such as lists of objects, to my Blazor components. While basic data binding seems straightforward, I'm unsure about the best practices for handling more intricate data scenarios. Specifically, I'm working with scenarios where I have nested data structures or need to update the UI based on changes within these structures.

Could someone provide guidance on how to efficiently bind complex data structures to Blazor components? Are there any recommended patterns or techniques for keeping the UI in sync with data changes? Additionally, I'd appreciate insights into how to handle user interactions that modify these complex data structures and trigger appropriate updates in the UI. Any code examples or step-by-step explanations would be immensely helpful in improving my understanding of this aspect of Blazor development.

Comment: Too broad. Pick a specific problem and post a [mre] for it.

Comment: This is not a Blazor specific issue.  You need to read up about Aggregates - search "Aggregate Root".  This particular SO answer is probably relevant to you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32782351/13065781.  This article provides a good insight - https://code-maze.com/csharp-design-pattern-aggregate/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment noted, this question is really too broad.  The best answer may be quite different for binding an array vs. a custom class, etc.

That said, one solution that can be made to work for many scenarios is to bind to a getter/setter and then do your extra work in the setter.  As an example, let's say we have:

```
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="this.InputValue">
```

Then we could have:

```
private string _inputValue;
public string InputValue {
    get { return (_inputValue); }
    set {
        _inputValue = value;
        // Do other work here, create object instances, deserialize the value into an object instance, whatever you want, etc.
    }
}
```

This same aproach can work for binding component parameters as well.